# Why does NGINX not find new static django files when putting up a new build?

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm running a Django application in Docker with NGINX, and Gunicorn on Ubuntu Server. It is a fairly large 'legacy' project so I am not the one who configured it. Why do I have to run `docker-compose down` before running `docker-compose up -d` to reflect the changes I have made to Django's static files? The docker file runs django's CLI command to collect the static files across project directories.

In both cases I ran `docker-compose build` before putting up or taking down.

Stopping the NGINX container first, and then putting up the container seemed to allow NGINX to find static files but why was NGINX unable to serve files added to another container?

The docker compose file being run:

```
version: '2'
services:
nginx:
  image: nginx:latest
  container_name: smi-nginx
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  volumes:
    - ./src:/src
    - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    - /static:/static
  depends_on:
    - web
web:
  build: .
  container_name: smi-App
  volumes:
    - /static:/static
  command: bash -c "gunicorn -w 3 -t 14400 --max-requests 75 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 project.wsgi:application"
  environment:
    - APPLEVEL=DEVELOPMENT
    - MachineID=99
    - DbUser=djangouser
    - Password=secret
  expose:
    - "5000"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the docker-compose.yml has a command for collectstatic on `up` ?

Comment: We can only guess without more information. Please share the `docker-compose.yaml` as well as `Dockerfile`s for any custom images.

Comment: Is caching enabled on nginx?

Comment: `docker file runs collectstatic` - so your static files are a part of the docker image. Which is not really a good idea. `why was NGINX unable to serve files added to another container?` I don't understand this. Btw, I have got not good assumptions that your static files are actually served by Django, not by Nginx. Unless you're sharing volumes between containers. So show your docker-compose file.